# Public project giving 401

Tags: azure-devops

I have a public project in Azure DevOps that isn't public. The settings show the project is public, the organization security polices allow public projects, but no one can access the project unless they are a member of a team. Am I understanding this wrong? I thought non-members of a public project should be able to Browse the code base, download code, view commits, branches, and pull requests. They get a 401. How do I set up a project so anyone with a Microsoft login can at least download the code?

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. If not, you can [contact customer cupport](https://support.microsoft.com/) to report your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have visited the organization rather than the project.

When you make a project public, anyone can access the project, but only users in the organization can access the organization. So you need to go directly to the url of the project.

For example, to access project B in organization A, you need to visit `https://dev.azure.com/{organization A}/{project B}` instead of `https://dev.azure.com/{organization A}`.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you!